# Access - Get counter (autoincrement primary key) during Insert

Tags: vb.net, ms-access, primary-key, auto-increment

MS-Access Database

```
Table: myTable
Field1: ID (COUNTER, which is autoincrement in Access)
Field2: SURNAME (VARCHAR)
Field3: NAME (VARCHAR)
```

I want to **get ID** returned, whenever I insert a row. Is there a way? (I am using VB.Net)

EDIT: 
**Solution using SELECT @@IDENTITY**

```
'Execute insert statement and return identity (autoincrement ID field)
Public Function executeInsertGetIdentity(ByVal insertStatement As String) As Integer
    ' Execute insert
    Dim myOleDbCommand As OleDbCommand
    myOleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand(insertStatement, connection)
    If myOleDbCommand.ExecuteNonQuery() < 1 Then Return 0
    ' Return identity
    Dim myOleDbCommand2 As OleDbCommand
    myOleDbCommand2 = New OleDbCommand("SELECT @@IDENTITY", connection)
    Dim myOleDbDataReader As OleDbDataReader = myOleDbCommand.ExecuteReader()
    myOleDbDataReader.Read()
    executeInsertGetIdentity = myOleDbDataReader.Item(0).ToString()
    myOleDbDataReader.Close()
End Function
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use @@Identity, step by step - [HOW TO: Retrieve the Identity Value While Inserting Records into Access Database By Using Visual Basic .NET](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/815629)

Comment: Thanks. Posted a complete solution using your answer

Comment: I was wondering. Is there a possibility that between 'INSERT' and 'SELECT @@IDENTITY', a second insert occurs from another user, this messing with the ID I get from 'SELECT @@IDENTITY', since the database is used by many users?

Comment: @@IDENTITY is maintained per connections, so, no, in your code it's not possible. However, one caveat: A2010 adds the ability to have the equivalent of triggers (table-level data macros) and if your first statement causes records to be inserted in another table with an Autonumber, you might get a wrong answer (I don't know if you do or not). In SQL Server, you have Scope_Identity() that takes care of that problem, but so far as I can tell, A2010 does not address this potential problem (possibly because it doesn't exist).